azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError while running Behave Python tests in Azure pipeline
I have created a Behave Cucumber with Python automation test framework to test the Azure resources. Until now I have running it locally but now it need to run as Azure pipeline. After configuring it into Azure pipeline, it throws following error
`
<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fef739b9610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

`
Logs
Scenario: Verify data gets deleted from Validated Study container          # features/clean_up.feature:3
Given the client is authenticated to validated study container           # features/steps/clean_up.py:6
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/behave/model.py", line 1329, in run
      match.run(runner.context)
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/behave/matchers.py", line 98, in run
      self.func(context, *args, **kwargs)
    File "features/steps/clean_up.py", line 9, in step_imp
      context.val_cont_client = context.client.get_brnz_container_client(
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/agent/_work/1/s/lib/storage_acc.py", line 88, in get_brnz_container_client
      assert container_client.exists(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 78, in wrapper_use_tracer
      return func(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_container_client.py", line 570, in exists
      self._client.container.get_properties(**kwargs)
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 78, in wrapper_use_tracer
      return func(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_generated/operations/_container_operations.py", line 1054, in get_properties
      pipeline_response: PipelineResponse = self._client._pipeline.run(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 230, in run
      return first_node.send(pipeline_request)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 86, in send
      response = self.next.send(request)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 86, in send
      response = self.next.send(request)
File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 86, in send
      response = self.next.send(request)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [Previous line repeated 2 more times]
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_redirect.py", line 197, in send
      response = self.next.send(request)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 86, in send
      response = self.next.send(request)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/policies.py", line 555, in send
      raise err
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/policies.py", line 529, in send
      response = self.next.send(request)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 86, in send
      response = self.next.send(request)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 86, in send
      response = self.next.send(request)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_authentication.py", line 126, in send
      response = self.next.send(request)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 86, in send
      response = self.next.send(request)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/policies.py", line 302, in send
      response = self.next.send(request)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 86, in send
      response = self.next.send(request)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 86, in send
      response = self.next.send(request)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 119, in send
      self._sender.send(request.http_request, **request.context.options),
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.2/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/transport/_requests_basic.py", line 386, in send
      raise error
  azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fef73c0c770>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
  




    

Please could someone guide with how to resolve this error? Can this be DNS issue or the code issue?
Here is the my yaml file
name: $(Date:yyyy-MM-dd).$(Rev:r) $(env)-trial-${{ parameters.clinicalTrialNumber }}-$(studyCode) clean-up
trigger: none
parameters:
- name: subscription
  displayName: Subscription
  type: string
  default: ''
  values:
    

- name: landingZoneNumber
  displayName: 'Landing Zone Number'
  type: string
  default: ''

- name: clinicalTrialNumber
  displayName: 'Clinical Trial Number'
  type: string
  default: ''

- name: sourceType
  displayName: 'Source type'
  type: string
  default: 'dev'
  values:
    - 'dev'
    - 'live'

variables:
- name: landingZoneNumber
  value: ${{ parameters.landingZoneNumber}}

- name: clinicalTrialNumber
  value: ${{ parameters.clinicalTrialNumber}}

- name: env
  ${{ if startsWith(parameters.subscription, 'azu-cie') }}:
    value: 'cie'
  ${{ if startsWith(parameters.subscription, 'azu-dev') }}:
    value: 'dev'
  ${{ if startsWith(parameters.subscription, 'azu-tst') }}:
    value: 'tst'
  

- name: variableGlobalTrialGroup
  

- name: variableTrialGroup
  

pool:
  name: $(poolName)
  vmImage: $(vmImage)

jobs:
  - deployment: trialCleanup
    displayName: 'Clean-up ${{ variables.env }}-trial-${{ parameters.clinicalTrialNumber }}'
    environment: ${{ variables.env }}
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: self
            clean: true
            fetchDepth: 2

          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            displayName: 'Use Python 3.12'
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '3.12'
              addToPath: true
              architecture: 'x64'

          - task: AzureCLI@2
            name: SPN
            continueOnError: false
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.subscription }}
              scriptType: pscore
              scriptLocation: 'InlineScript'
              addSpnToEnvironment: true
              inlineScript: |
                

          - script: |
              pip --version
              python -m pip install --upgrade pip
              pip cache purge
              pip install -r requirements.txt
            displayName: 'py requirements'

          - script: env | sort
            displayName: 'Display Env variables'

          - task: AzureCLI@2
            name: runBehaveCleanUp
            displayName: 'Behave clean-up trial-${{ parameters.clinicalTrialNumber}}'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.subscription }}
              scriptType: 'bash'
              scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
              inlineScript: |
                pip install pytest-azurepipelines
                behave --no-capture --no-color ./features/clean_up.feature
              addSpnToEnvironment: true
              failOnStandardError: true
         

      

`

I noticed that pool is set in your yaml: pool:    name: $(poolName)    vmImage: $(vmImage). What agent are you using? If it is a self-hosted agent, you can delete vmImage: $(vmImage). In addition, is the account under which the pipeline is run the same as the user when it is successfully executed locally? Sometimes the account of the pipeline lacks permissions and can cause problems.
